# swift: how to adjust table view's height to fit super view's height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a viewController into which I dragged a tableView, but when I load data in the tableView I get a scroll, what I want is to extend this tableView to its height to fill its superView. I tried to resize the tableView by setting `tableView.frame.height = tableView.contentSize.height` in `viewDidAppear` and it worked but I don't get a scroll in the superView, the tableView just got expanded and the content is down the view but I cant scroll, I tried to put this tableView inside a scrollView but still the same thing, what can I do?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of what is happening so I can help you with this

Comment: The contentSize of your table view is most likely much taller than your iPad's screen. That's why you can't scroll it if you assign contentSize to the frame of the table view — the table view is just too tall and goes beyond the screen boundaries. Try using AutoLayout with a similar vertical constraint: `V:|[image][table]|`. You can read about the AutoLayout Visual Format Language here https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage.html

Answer (score 0):

yourTableview.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)

Basically what you did was adjust the height of the tableView to be is the height if its content rather than the height of the screen (the content height is larger than the screen)

The table should carry the height of the screen (or any height you want) and if your content is bigger than the frame of your tableView it will automatically have the scrolling enabled.

Hope this helps!

Comment: already did this and it worked but the view dose not resize to fit the table size

Comment: your table height is bigger than the screen. I edited my answer please check

Comment: you want all the views to fit into the screen?

Comment: yes, and when i did `self.view.sizeToFit()` I lose the tableView new size, I just get back to its original size

Comment: but if the size of your ocntent is larger than the screen. how do you want to let it fit? you want to zoom them out to fir you mean?

Comment: no, if the size is lager I want to be able to scroll down to it

Comment: and when you put the tableview size as your screen height, you said it does and the scroll appears. So what is the problem exactly?

Comment: no the table dose get longer but there is no scroll

Answer (score 0):

If you want your scrollview to be scrollable, you need to indicate its `contentSize` by dynamically calculating the height of its nested components:

```
scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
scrollView.contentSize = imageView.frame.height + tableview1.frame.height + tableview2.frame.height + netLabel.frame.height
```

Notice that you may also have to include your margins' height

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to add the constraint of height of my table as an Outlet like this `@IBOutlet weak var myConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!`, and the do `myConstraint.constant = myTable.contentSize.height` in `viewDidAppear`